# How can I assign properties from an object to a HTML element

Tags: javascript

I have got an object in Js and some cards in HTML, now how can I assign the properties from that object to a specific card, so when I use the filter function in Js I could display the cards that matches the properties I filtered? Is it possible to do in pure Js, without using Json or jQuery?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9LRC.jpg (HTML cards)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ciw1.jpg (Js object

```js
const vehicles = [{ 
  id: 01,
  type: 'car',
  model: 'toyota aygo',
  price: 53,
  transmission: 'manual',
  passengers: '4'
},
{
  id: 02,
  type: 'car',
  model: 'ford focus',
  price: 64,
  transmission: 'automatic',
  passengers: '5'
},
{
  id: 03,
  type: 'car',
  model: 'citroen 2cv',
  price: 30,
  transmission: 'manual',
  passengers: '2'
},
{
  id: 04,
  type: 'car',
  model: 'lamborghini huracan spyder',
  price: 2400,
  transmission: 'manual',
  passengers: '2'
},
{
  id: 05,
  type: 'suv',
  model: 'volvo xc60',
  price: 185,
  transmission: 'manual',
  passengers: '5'
},
{
  id: 06,
  type: 'suv',
  model: 'ford kuga',
  price: 92,
  transmission: 'automatic',
  passengers: '5'
},
{
  id: 07,
  type: 'suv',
  model: 'range rover sport',
  price: 240,
  transmission: 'automatic',
  passengers: '5'
},
{
  id: 08,
  type: 'van',
  model: 'vauxhall vivaro',
  price: 60,
  transmission: 'manual',
  passengers: '3'
},
{
  id: 09,
  type: 'van',
  model: 'renault kangoo',
  price: 50,
  transmission: 'manual',
  passengers: '2'
},
{
  id: 10,
  type: 'carrier',
  model: 'seat alhambra',
  price: 200,
  transmission: 'automatic',
  passengers: '7'
}
]


/*const matchingVehicle = vehicles.filter(function(vehicle){
  if(vehicle.type == checkValue && vehicle.passengers == pasNum){
    return true
  } 
    return false
})

matchingVehicle.forEach(function(vehicle){
  console.log(vehicle.model)
 
})*/
```

```css
.price {
  font-family: "Popins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #eb232c;
  display: flex;
}

.price_icon {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.price_num {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
}

.car_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
.car_info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.info_icon {
  color: #eb232c;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.info_text {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #1b232f;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.btn_cool {
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 10px 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #1b232f;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 0.4 linear;
  position: relative;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: #eb232c;
}

.btn::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1b232f;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 1.6, 0.4, 0.7);
}

.btn1::before {
  transform: scaleX(0);
}

.btn1:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.btn2 {
  color: #1b232f;
}

/* Indicators */

.indicator {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.indicator div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ecf1f8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0 3px;
}

.indicator div.active {
  background: #eb232c;
}

/* Section choose */

.choose_content {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 40px;
}

.choose_header {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: inline-block;
}

.choose_header::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #1b232f;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.choose_inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.choose_item {
  filter: brightness(80%);
  transition: filter 0.5s ease;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
}

.choose_title {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 6px 32px;
  background-color: #eb232c;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.choose_title h3 {
  font-family: "Poppins", serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.choose_item:hover {
  filter: brightness(100%);
}

.choose_img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: center;
  transition: 1s;
}

.choose_img:hover {
  width: 330px;
  height: 330px;
  position: center;
}

.carrier1,
.van1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

/* Section why */

.why {
  background-color: #ecf1f8;
  padding: 5px;
}

.why_inner {
  display: flex;
  padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
}

.why_box {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.why_box:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.why_box:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.why_logo {
  width: 20%;
}

.why_logo i {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 13px;
  margin: -20px 30px 0 0;
  color: #eb232c;
  /* border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px red solid; */
}

.why_logo .pound {
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

.why_content {
  width: 70%;
  text-align: left;
}

.why_header h2 {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #1b232f;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.why_text p {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: #777;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

/* Browse by type section */

span {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.category_main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.category_img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 210px;
}

.post_collect {
  margin: auto;
}

.category_head {
  margin: 30px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.category_head ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.category_head ul li {
  color: #1b232f;
  padding: 5px;
}

.category_icon {
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.category_title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  color: #eb232c;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.category_title li {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.category_title li::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #eb232c;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.category_title li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.posts-main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.post-img {
  position: relative;
}

.category_name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.car {
  background: #1b232f;
}

.suvs {
  background: #eb232c;
}

.vans {
  background: #777;
}

.carriers {
  background: #8a99a7;
}

.post-content {
  padding: 10px;
}

.post-content-top {
  background: #fff;
  color: #1b232f;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.post-content-top span {
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #eb232c;
}

hr {
  height: 2px;
  background: #888;
  border: none;
}

.post-content-bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #888888;
  align-items: center;
}

em {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #1b232f;
}

strong {
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.active2 {
  color: #eb232c;
  background-color: #888888;
}

/* Testimonias */

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-box {
  position: relative;
}

/* Slides */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #1b232f;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  color: #eb232c;
}

/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */
.dot-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #777;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */
.active3,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #eb232c;
}

/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */
q {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #888;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

/* Add a blue color to the author */

.customer_img {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.customer_icon {
  max-width: 80px;
  max-height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.author_info {
  padding: 20px;
}

.author_name {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #1b232f;
}

.author_job {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #eb232c;
}

/* Book Page */

.book {
  background: url(img/Citroen2CV.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.container-book {
  transform: translateY(150%);
}

.choice_content {
  padding: 20px 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.choice_text h2 {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  /* Category */

  .posts-main-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }

  .category_img {
    height: 350px;
  }

  /* Why chose us */

  .why_inner {
    padding: 20px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  /* TextBox Hero Slider */
  .text_box {
    max-width: 500px;
    top: 20%;
  }

  .title {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
  .price_icon {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }

  .price_num {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }

  .car_info {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }

  .info_text {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }

  .btn {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    padding: 8px 14px;
  }

  /* Why Choose Us */

  .why_inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }

  .why_box {
    padding: 10px 0;
  }

  .choose_header {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }

  /* Category */

  .category_img {
    height: auto;
  }

  /* Menu */
  .social {
    display: none;
  }

  /* Burger Menu */

  .nav_links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 9vh;
    width: 50%;

    background-color: #1b232f;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;

    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  }

  .menu li {
    padding: 20px;
  }

  .active1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .fa-times {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 760px) {
  .posts-main-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }

  .choose_inner {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-gap: 40px;
  }

  .carrier1,
  .van1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  /* Gallery */

  .category_head {
    padding: 20px;
  }

  .category_head ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  /* TextBox Hero Slider */

  .text_box {
    max-width: 300px;
    top: 20%;
  }

  .title {
    font-size: 0.6rem;
  }

  .price {
    padding-left: 60px;
  }

  .price_icon {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }

  .price_num {
    font-size: 0.6rem;
  }

  .car_wrapper {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .car_info {
    font-size: 0.6rem;
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }

  .info_text {
    font-size: 0.6rem;
  }

  .btn {
    font-size: 0.6rem;
    padding: 8px 14px;
  }

  /* H2 Element */

  .choose_header {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  /* Gallery */

  .category_head {
    padding: 20px;
  }

  .category_head ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

.nav_active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  opacity: 1;
}

.fa-bars-active {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
            <div class="post-collect">
                <div class="posts-main-container posts-book">
                    <div class="all cars any manual allpas four" id="01">
                        <div class="post-img">
                            <img class="category_img" src="img/ToyotaAygo.jpg" alt="ToyotaAygo">
                            <span class="category_name car">Car</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="post-content">
                            <div class="post-content-top">
                                <span class="veh-name"><i class="fa fa-car"><em>Toyota Aygo</em></i></span>
                                <span class="post-cost"><i class="fas fa-pound-sign"></i><em>53</em></span>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="post-content-bottom">
                                <span><i class="fas fa-car"></i><strong>Car</strong></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-cog"></i><strong>Manual</strong></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><strong>4</strong></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="all cars any automatic allpas five">
                        <div class="post-img">
                            <img class="category_img" src="img/FordFocusFilter.jpg" alt="FordFocus">
                            <span class="category_name car">Car</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="post-content">
                            <div class="post-content-top">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-car"><em>Ford Focus</em></i></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-pound-sign"></i><em>64</em></span>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="post-content-bottom">
                                <span><i class="fas fa-car"></i><strong>Car</strong></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-cog"></i><strong>Automtic</strong></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><strong>5</strong></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="all cars any manual allpas two">
                        <div class="post-img">
                            <img class="category_img" src="img/Citroen2CV.jpg" alt="Citroen2CV">
                            <span class="category_name car">Car</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="post-content">
                            <div class="post-content-top">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-car"><em>Citroen 2CV</em></i></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-pound-sign"></i><em>30</em></span>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="post-content-bottom">
                                <span><i class="fas fa-car"></i><strong>Car</strong></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-cog"></i><strong>Manual</strong></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><strong>2</strong></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="all cars any manual allpas two">
                        <div class="post-img">
                            <img class="category_img" src="img/LamborghiniHuracanFilter.jpg" alt="Lamborghini">
                            <span class="category_name car">Car</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="post-content">
                            <div class="post-content-top">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-car"><em>Lamborghini</em></i></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-pound-sign"></i><em>2400</em></span>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="post-content-bottom">
                                <span><i class="fas fa-car"></i><strong>Car</strong></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-cog"></i><strong>Manual</strong></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><strong>2</strong></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="all suv any manual allpas five">
                        <div class="post-img">
                            <img class="category_img" src="img/Volvoxc60Filter.jpg" alt="Lamborghini">
                            <span class="category_name suvs">SUV</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="post-content">
                            <div class="post-content-top">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-car"><em>Volvo XC60</em></i></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-pound-sign"></i><em>185</em></span>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="post-content-bottom">
                                <span><i class="fas fa-car"></i><strong>SUV</strong></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-cog"></i><strong>Manual</strong></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><strong>5</strong></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="all suv any automatic allpas five">
                        <div class="post-img">
                            <img  class="category_img" src="img/FordKugaGrid.jpg" alt="Lamborghini">
                            <span class="category_name suvs">SUv</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="post-content">
                            <div class="post-content-top">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-car"><em>Ford Kuga</em></i></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-pound-sign"></i><em>92</em></span>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="post-content-bottom">
                                <span><i class="fas fa-car"></i><strong>SUV</strong></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-cog"></i><strong>Automatic</strong></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><strong>5</strong></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="all suv any automatic allpas five">
                        <div class="post-img">
                            <img class="category_img" src="img/RangeRoverGrid.jpg" alt="Lamborghini">
                            <span class="category_name suvs">SUV</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="post-content">
                            <div class="post-content-top">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-car"><em>Range Rover Sport</em></i></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-pound-sign"></i><em>240</em></span>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="post-content-bottom">
                                <span><i class="fas fa-car"></i><strong>SUV</strong></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-cog"></i><strong>Automatic</strong></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><strong>5</strong></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="all van any manual allpas three">
                        <div class="post-img">
                            <img class="category_img" src="img/VauxhallVivaroGrid.jpg" alt="Lamborghini">
                            <span class="category_name vans">Van</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="post-content">
                            <div class="post-content-top">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-car"><em>Vauxhall Vivaro</em></i></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-pound-sign"></i><em>60</em></span>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="post-content-bottom">
                                <span><i class="fas fa-car"></i><strong>Van</strong></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-cog"></i><strong>Manual</strong></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><strong>3</strong></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="all van any manual allpas two">
                        <div class="post-img">
                            <img class="category_img" src="img/RenaultKangooGrid.jpg" alt="Lamborghini">
                            <span class="category_name vans">Van</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="post-content">
                            <div class="post-content-top">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-car"><em>Renault Kangoo</em></i></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-pound-sign"></i><em>50</em></span>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="post-content-bottom">
                                <span><i class="fas fa-car"></i><strong>Van</strong></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-cog"></i><strong>Manual</strong></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><strong>2</strong></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="all people carrier any automatic allpas seven">
                        <div class="post-img">
                            <img class="category_img" src="img/SeatAlhambraGrid.jpg" alt="Lamborghini">
                            <span class="category_name carriers">People Carrier</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="post-content">
                            <div class="post-content-top">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-car"><em>Seat Alhambra</em></i></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-pound-sign"></i><em>200</em></span>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="post-content-bottom">
                                <span><i class="fas fa-car"></i><strong>People Carrier</strong></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-cog"></i><strong>Automatic</strong></span>
                                <span><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><strong>7</strong></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

)

Comment: There is a lot of code in your question, please try to reduce it to a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this, filter data and add on html

```
 vehicleFiltered = [];
  
  
  const matchingVehicle = vehicles.filter(function(vehicle){
    if(vehicle.type == 'suv' && vehicle.passengers == 5){
      vehicleFiltered.push({
          id: vehicle.id,
        type: vehicle.type,
        model: vehicle.model,
        price: vehicle.price,
        transmission: vehicle.transmission,
        passengers: vehicle.passengers
      }) 
     // console.log(vehicleFiltered)
     
    } 
  })
  


this.populate();

function populate(){

    ul = document.createElement('ul');

    document.getElementById('myItemList').appendChild(ul);
    
    vehicleFiltered.forEach(function (item) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    
    li.innerHTML += item.model;
    });
  }
```